# Read yes/no field from access - Display on java as String

Tags: java, string, ms-access

I am having trouble converting an int to string.

I use java to connect to a database (Access).

Now I'm trying to retrieve the value from a YES/NO Field Access but it'sa  check box

```
jlbABC.setText(rs.getString("RightWrong"));
```

The answer I get is 1 if it is True(YES), and 0 if is False (NO)

How do I change the answer from 1 to YES and 0 to NO?

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand at all what you want, but here is how I normally convert any integer into a string literal.

```
String values[] = new String[]{"NO", "YES"};
int myValue = ... wherever it comes from;
String myConvertedValue = values[myValue];
```

You may also check if myValue is in bounds of the array of values.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to set the value of a string based on if it is a 0 or a 1 you could use this.

```
int i = rs.getInt("RightWrong");
String yesno = i == 1 ? "YES" : "NO";
```

This has the benefit of saying that the result will be "YES" if the value is 1 or "NO" otherwise.